# Get element by cursor position in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I'm writing an automation testing framework using Selenium. I am trying to Locate which element my cursor is pointing to.

for eg. there are two textbox `textbox1` and `textbox2`. If I perform a tab swift operation in java to move focus form `textbox1` to `textbox2` such that now `textbox2` is at focus and the cursor position is moved, so is their any way to find in java whether the focus is actually shifted or not..

I usually try finding element such as,`id`,`name`,`css`,`xpath`.eg

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login_error")).getText().equals("Please enter Valid Data")
```

but finding by cursor is a new  challenge for me which I am not getting through.
thanks in advance

Comment: What code you have tried , please share that so can check and correct it.

Comment: I wish you could downvote comments like the one above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if a specific element has focus, call `element.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement())`

[More info in this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025282/selenium-check-if-a-webelement-has-the-focus)

Comment: I want to find the id or name of the element on focus, such that [id="textbox2" equals to activeElement]....

Comment: @Val then you can just try `driver.findElement(By.Id("textbox2")).equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement())`